# Non-Monogenic Quadratic Extensions

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, quadratics, extension-field

Fix a quadratic extension of global fields $L/K$; i.e., $[L:K]=2$. Must there exist some $\alpha\in\mathcal O_L$ such that $\mathcal O_L=\mathcal O_K[\alpha]$?

Of course, the answer is positive for $K=\mathbb Q$, but I suspect the answer is negative in general. If the statement is false, is there some reasonably large (e.g., infinite) family of global fields $K$ for which the statement is true?

Comment: For the second part, I think you can consider the extensions $\mathbb{Q}(\mu_n)/\mathbb{Q}(\mu_n)^+$.

Comment: There are quadratic extensions that do not possess a relative integral basis (google should help). Such a relative integral basis exists if $K$ has class number $1$, but does not exist in general.

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer My example is clearly the simplest and it doesn't appear on top google results

Comment: @franzlemmermeyer May I have a reference to the class-number-$1$ result? I was not aware of this.

Comment: @DeriveFoiler if $L/K$ has degree $n$ and $K$ has class number $1$, then $\mathcal O_K$ is a PID, so $\mathcal O_L$ as an $\mathcal O_K$-module is free of rank $n$: it is isomorphic to $\mathcal O_K^n$. That is what it means to have a relative integral basis (not necessarily a power basis). The proof is the same as that showing a ring of integers is a finite free $\mathbf Z$-module.

Comment: I apologize. I misread and thought the claim was that $K$ having class number $1$ implies the extension of number rings was monogenic. Thank you all.

Comment: It *does* imply that, but only because $L/K$ has degree $2$. See the update to my answer.

Comment: @reuns I added a family of examples that includes yours as a special case to the end of https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/nopowerbasis.pdf.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An infinite set of examples can be found at https://kconrad.math.uconn.edu/blurbs/gradnumthy/notfree.pdf.
In all of these examples, $\mathcal O_K$ is not a PID.

When $\mathcal O_K$ is a PID, $\mathcal O_L$ is monogenic as an $\mathcal O_K$-module because $[L:K] = 2$: let’s show there is an $\mathcal O_K$-basis containing $1$, and writing that basis as $\{1,\alpha\}$ makes $\mathcal O_L = \mathcal O_K[\alpha]$. (Such reasoning breaks down for extensions of degree greater than $2$, and there are many examples of non-monogenic extensions of degree $3$ when $\mathcal O_K$ is a PID, in fact in the simplest case when $\mathcal O_K = \mathbf Z$.)

There is *some* $\mathcal O_K$-basis $\{\alpha_1,\alpha_2\}$ of $\mathcal O_L$ since $\mathcal O_K$ is a PID and $L/K$ is quadratic. Relative to this basis, we can write
$$
1 = a_1\alpha_1 + a_2\alpha_2
$$
where $a_1$ and $a_2$ are in $\mathcal O_K$. That equation implies a common factor of $a_1$ and $a_2$ in $\mathcal O_K$ is a unit in $\mathcal O_L$, and thus in $\mathcal O_K$, so $a_1$ and $a_2$ are relatively prime in $\mathcal O_K$. Thus
$$
a_1b_1+a_2b_2= 1
$$
for some $b_1$ and $b_2$ in $\mathcal O_K$.
Set
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
a_1&a_2\\-b_2&b_1
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\alpha_1\\ \alpha_2
\end{pmatrix}=
\begin{pmatrix}
1\\ \alpha
\end{pmatrix}.
$$
That $2\times 2$ matrix with entries in $\mathcal O_K$ has determinant $1$, so $1$ and $\alpha$ have the same $\mathcal O_K$-span as $\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$. Hence
$$
\mathcal O_L = \mathcal O_K + \mathcal O_K\alpha = \mathcal O_K[\alpha].
$$

Answer (score 1):

Try $$O_K=\Bbb{Z}[\sqrt{-5}],\qquad L= K(\sqrt2)$$
$$O_L = O_K \oplus \frac{\sqrt2}2 I, \qquad I=2O_K+(1+\sqrt{-5})O_K$$

$O_L/O_K\cong I \not\cong O_K$ as $O_K$-module, so $O_L$ can't be monogenic.